# sed like stream editor for open files using open syscall

Tags: linux

I'm working with a software which reads a trace file with multiple entries, each of which are of format:

```
<...>,<...>,<64 character string>
```

This 64 character string is in my case constitute entirely of '0'.

Would it be possible to have something like sed for file streams (not stdin, file stream opened using open syscall) which would allow me to feed the said program a file with following entries:

```
<...>,<...>,&
```

and the program would replace '&' with 64 '0's. The problem with using sed on the trace file itself before executing the program is the limited space available on the machine.

My current plan is to use ptrace to intercept read syscalls and make it appear for the program as if it is reading a normal file, would that be a good idea?

---

<sub>**(edit)**</sub>
The program parses the file only once.

Comment: @Mawg you are right, it belongs to unix.stackexchange more than it does here. Is it possible to move this question there? Thanks

Comment: A moderator can, but I can't :-/  I have flagged it, so hopefully it will be migrated. Wait a day or so, and if no migration, then delete this & post again there, I guess. If they can't help on Unix & Linux, we can probably recommend an app for it on S/W recommendations.

Comment: Is the file opened by the program a file named on the command line? In that case you should still be able to give it `/dev/stdin` as the filename while piping `sed` to it.

Comment: @Kusalananda That worked, thanks! Consider answering the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda Would this work if the program didn't read the input file line by line?

Comment: @lol In what manner does the program read the file? As long as it doesn't try to read the file many times, it would work (standard input is not seekable). I avoid answering questions that don't give all details. I will answer this one as soon as I know that the answer is valid.

Comment: Yes it doesn't, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072125/how-does-a-pipe-work-in-linux) that the processes is suspended till input is updated (when multiple programs are in a chain of 'pipes'). This is a really nice way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/,[^,]*$/,\&/' <file | program /dev/stdin
```

This assumes that the program must be given the filename on the command line and that it does not try to do seeks backwards or forwards in the file (standard input is not generally seekable).

The special file `/dev/stdin` will contain the contents of the standard input stream of the process.  Above, we use this fact to send the modified contents of `file` to the program using a standard Unix pipe on the command line, even though the program normally does not read its standard input stream.

The `sed` expression will replace everything after the last comma on each line of `file` with a `&`.

Comment: What if the program seeks through the file? Can the output be written to some other file?

Comment: @lol I'm not 100% certain, but skipping _forwards_ may _possibly_ be ok, but I would avoid it (I simply haven't tested this). The ideal situation would be to fully preprocess the input file and _then_ give it to the program.